# Integrating iPerf3 Client in a React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, iperf, iperf3

I'm currently working on a project where I need to integrate the functionality of an iPerf3 client within a React Native application. I've searched extensively on npmjs but haven't found any existing packages that provide this capability.

Has anyone successfully implemented an iPerf3 client in a React Native app? If so, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this. Insights on potential workarounds or methods to effectively incorporate iPerf3 client functionalities into a React Native environment would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!